# confused by printf in linux bash

Tags: bash, printf

I'm confused by `printf`, here is what I did,

```
printf "%x" 1024  # output 400
printf \\x400  # output @0
printf \\x400 | od -An -tu4  # output 12352, why 12352 not 1024?
```

Answer (score 3):

From `man printf`:

> Interpreted sequences are:
>   ...
>   \xHH   byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)

You're running it with `\x400`, which are *three digits*. `printf` prints `@`, which is the character encoded by `\x40`, and the remaining `0` is printed as a literal character, thus `@0`, which is *not* a representation of the hexadecimal value `400`.

What you want is

```
printf \\x00\\x04 | od -An -tu4
```

which prints `1024`.

Comment: Only if you can manage to fit it in just two hexadecimal digits, as the manual says.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `\x` notation you can only express one or two hex. digits (see `man bash`), but if you use `0x` notation you can use an odd number of digits:

```
/home/user1> printf "0x%x\n" 1024
0x400
/home/user1> printf '%d\n' 0x400
1024
```